# How to add a projection to axis in matplotlib when using subplot2grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot five maps in five different subplots using cartopy. What I want to do is to plot three maps in the upper row, and the two remaining maps in the lower row, but have these two last subplots centralized. I managed to do that adding the subplot axes using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (0, 0), colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (0, 2), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (0, 4), colspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (1, 1), colspan=2)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (1, 3), colspan=2)
```

however I can't find a way to create these subplots with a cartographic projection. Normally, for an even number of subplots I would do:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
fig, Ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=3, subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()),constrained_layout=True)
```

But I don't know how to do that using subplot2grid. Is this possible or is there another way to create maps spaning more than one row or column in matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`subplot2grid`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html)
has

> ```
> **kwargs  
>      Additional keyword arguments are handed to add_subplot.
> ```

and `add_subplot` supports the `projection=` keyword argument.  Hence

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 6), (0, 0), colspan=2, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

is all that you need.